# Haskell string replace

Tags: string, haskell, replace

How do I replace a character with multiple characters in a string.
I can replace a character with another character with below:

```
  replaceO [] = []
  replaceO (x:xs) =
     if x == '('
     then '\n' : replaceO xs
     else x : replaceO xs
```

But I want to replace '(' with "\n\t\t", not just '\n'.

---------- UPDATE --------------
Based on the answer below, can I make that a function that accepts a string and returns a string like this:

```
ReplaceFun str :: String -> String
ReplaceFun str = do
    concatMap (\str -> if str == '.' then "foo" else [str])
```

This doesn't work, can someone point out my mistake? I am very new to Haskell.

Here is what I have for nested indentation:

```
replaceO (x:xs) n l =
    if x == '('
    then "\n" ++ (showTabs n "-") ++ replaceO xs (n + 1) 'l'
    else
        if x == ')'
        then "\n" ++ (showTabs n "-") ++ replaceO xs (n - 1) 'l'
        else x : replaceO xs n 'l'
```

Comment: You haven't given `concatMap` enough arguments - the rhs of `replaceFun` (also note the lowercase) should have type `String` but `concatMap (\str -> if str == '.' then "foo" else [str])` has type `String -> String`. You probably want `replaceFun = concatMap (\str -> if str == '.' then "foo" else [str])`

Answer (score 5):

Just use `concatMap`

```
Prelude> concatMap (\x -> if x == '.' then "foo" else [x]) "example..."
"examplefoofoofoo"
```

Comment: Can you define this as a function please? I can't get it working.

Comment: I did it like this, but doesn't work: replaceFun w :: String -> String  replaceFun w = do concatMap (\x -> if x == '.' then "foo" else [x])

Comment: can you have a look at the updated part of the question?

Comment: @2D3D4D `f = concatMap (\x -> if x == '.' then "foo" else [x])`  or more generally `f a b s = concatMap (\x -> if x == a then b else [x]) s`

Answer (score 2):

expanding your example, you can substitute "\n\t\t" for "(" by just prepending multiple things to the result of the recursive call

```
replace1 [] = []
replace1 (x:xs) =
   if x == '('
   then '\n' : '\t' : '\t' : replace1 xs
   else x : replace1 xs
```

of course, this is equivalent to using `"\n\t\t" ++`

```
replace2 [] = []
replace2 (x:xs) =
   if x == '('
   then "\n\t\t" ++ replace2 xs
   else x : replace2 xs
```

if we note that `x :` is equivalent to `[x] ++`

```
replace3 [] = []
replace3 (x:xs) =
   if x == '('
   then "\n\t\t" ++ replace3 xs
   else [x] ++ replace3 xs
```

then we can factor out the repeated recursive call

```
replace4 [] = []
replace4 (x:xs) = (if x == '(' then "\n\t\t" else [x]) ++ replace4 xs
```

then for clarity, we could filter out the `if` statement into a function:

```
replace5 [] = []
replace5 (x:xs) = f x ++ replace5 xs
  where f x = if x == '(' 
              then "\n\t\t" 
              else [x]
```

we could then reorganize our code - rather than alternately applying `f` to each `x` and 
appending it to our results, we could apply `f` to all the `xs` and then concatenate all the results:

```
replace6 xs = concat $ map f xs
  where f x = if x == '(' 
              then "\n\t\t" 
              else [x]
```

But `concat $ map f xs` is used so often that it has another name:

```
replace7 xs = concatMap f xs
  where f x = if x == '(' 
              then "\n\t\t" 
              else [x]
```

Actually, it has another one too, because `[]` is a monad:

```
replace8 xs = xs >>= f
  where f x = if x == '(' 
              then "\n\t\t" 
              else [x]
```

But if we're doing that, we might as well go full Monad:

```
replace9 xs = do
  x <- xs
  if x == '(' 
     then "\n\t\t" 
     else [x]
```

But I'd probably just stop at `replace7`, personally.

Comment: Thanks @rampion, just realized something, I wanted to use this to pretty print a tree. But all nodes will end up in the same indentation. I wanted to increase the indenting for each nested node. Is that easily possible?

Comment: Sure! look at one of the early versions. What if `replace2` took another argument, `n`, for how many tabs to insert after it replaced a '(' with a newline? Now the recursive call takes two arguments - the rest of the string and the number of tabs. What would you give the recursive call if (a) `x` wasn't a parenthesis, (b) it was an open paren, or (c) it was a close paren?

Comment: If it was not a parenthesis, then no replacement needed. If an open parenthesis, then we replace \n and \t (for each level of nested). Close parenthesis can be replaced by empty string I think.

Comment: I tried to do it, but with no luck. I have experience with C, and this is my first attempt with Haskell, can you add this change to your code as well please?

Comment: Show me how far you got following my questions above! Did you define a new `replace` function that took two arguments, `xs` and `n`?

Comment: please have a look at the function i added at the bottom of the question.

Comment: 2D3D4D: good start! now consider what you want "a(a(a(a(" to look like, and walk through your implementation using that as the input. See if you get what you want. See what goes wrong.

Comment: so for every "(" I am adding a "\n" and increasing the number of "\t", and for every ")", I am adding a "\n" and decreasing the number of "\t". I have changed the function, can you have a look? Now, logically I know how this should be done. But in Haskell, I get errors.

Comment: This is the error that I get using the code I added at the bottom of the question: Expecting one more argument to ‘[]’
    Expected a type, but ‘[]’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    In the type signature for ‘replace2’: replace2 :: [] -> Int -> []

Comment: Can't figure out why it doesn't accept the second argument.

Comment: how can I repeat a charater, like (n * '\t'), repeating '\t' n times?

Comment: 2D3D4D: You're [looking for `replicate`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+a+-%3E+[a])

Comment: I got it working except it never ends. So I need to check at the begining to see if it is null?

Comment: Yup, just like in your original version.